# Can't find Cmder in program files

Tags: windows, cmder

I've been having trouble finding the cmder inside windows program files. I wanted to make a shortcut to it so that I can easily access it using windows docker but can't find the location. I only have cmder now pinned on my taskbar but I would like to know it's directory path. Thanks in advance.

I am using windows x64bit

Comment: Already solved it. It's just located inside my local folder. I forgot it's not installed. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Open a command line window.
Enter "dir Cmder.exe /s"

Answer (score 0):

It's relative to where you installed it. To find out right-click cmder in your taskbar, and you will see that it says "cmder.exe - shortcut", right-click it again and access properties. In the target field you will see your path.